# Functions with variable arguments. How does open() work?

Tags: c, linux

I have to write a function that accepts a variable number of arguments, similar to the open() function

```
int open (const char *filename, int flags[, mode_t mode])
```

1. I had a look at the va_list functionality, but how can I find out how many arguments the user has supplied? I dont want to have a parameter in the function that indicates this.
2. Being a sort of newbie, where can I look how the open() function is implemented? How does open() know whether the user has supplied the *mode* argument or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You cannot.  The caller must either supply a trailing sentinel argument (e.g. a `0`), or explicitly tell the function how many arguments to expect (e.g. the format fields in `printf`).
2. `open` knows to expect the third argument because you will have set the `O_CREAT` flag in the `flags` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Copied straight from the [GCC page](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example).

Here is a complete sample function that accepts a variable number of arguments. The first argument to the function is the count of remaining arguments, which are added up and the result returned. While trivial, this function is sufficient to illustrate how to use the variable arguments facility.

```
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int
 add_em_up (int count,...)
 {
   va_list ap;
   int i, sum;

   va_start (ap, count);         /* Initialize the argument list. */

   sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
     sum += va_arg (ap, int);    /* Get the next argument value. */

   va_end (ap);                  /* Clean up. */
   return sum;
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   /* This call prints 16. */
   printf ("%d\n", add_em_up (3, 5, 5, 6));

   /* This call prints 55. */
   printf ("%d\n", add_em_up (10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Here , count says how many arguments the user has supplied. Thats what I dont want. If you see the open() function, there is no count argument.

Comment: I think the point was that `open` doesn't take any argument specifying if the third parameter is passed or not.  So, your example doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. You have to somehow include the information of how many extra parameters are there in the call.

Comment: how does the open() function work, since there is no way the user says how many extra parameters there are. Also, if you read the value of the mode argument in open(), how would u know its user supplied and not some random value?

Comment: @horizon_06 open knows because you specify O_CREAT in the flags. If you: Specify O_CREAT and do not supply a 3. argument, open() will not know, and you will get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is variadic function implementations. [Here is a doc](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Variadic-Functions.html) that will walk you through the entire chain.

Answer (score 1):

It does use O_CREAT.

I find the implementation from source of kernel 6.1.0-9-amd64:

```c
static __attribute__((unused))
int open(const char *path, int flags, ...)
{
    mode_t mode = 0;
    int ret;

    if (flags & O_CREAT) {
        va_list args;

        va_start(args, flags);
        mode = va_arg(args, mode_t);
        va_end(args);
    }

    ret = sys_open(path, flags, mode);

    if (ret < 0) {
        SET_ERRNO(-ret);
        ret = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer to the question, "How does `open` know if it was passed two or three arguments?" is: *it's magic*.  The long answer is that the implementation is allowed to do certain things that you are not (within standard C, that is).

Another example is `main`.  It has two valid prototypes:

```
int main(void);
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]); /* or equivalent */
```

The implementation must allow you to use any of the two, and "deduce", which is the one you used.

The answer to the question, "How can I do something similar in my code?", is: *you can't*, at least not within the constraints imposed by the C standard.

Comment: The answer by Oli Charlesworth is what I was looking for, so basically, either include a trailing sentinel value, or explicitly say how many arguments to expect.

Comment: -1: `open` is *not* magic.  It simply uses the flags to determine what to expect.

Comment: @Oli: `open` is not magic, but the implementation of `open`, which allows one to pass either two or three parameters to it is "magic", in the sense that it can't be done in standard C.  If it weren't "magic", it would be possible to write `open`-like function in *standard* C (taking either 2 or 3 parameters).

Comment: @Alok: Of course it is possible!  If a particular flag is set, then look for a third parameter.

Comment: @Oli: in other words, can you write a function `add()` in standard C, which will add either 2 or 3 numbers passed to it, depending upon whether the first number is negative or not?  So, I should be able to call `add(1, 2, 3);` to get `6`, and `add(-1, 5);` to get 4?  Note that I must be able to call `add()` with different number of parameters.

Comment: @Oli: but then you are *requiring* the user to *always* pass 3 parameters.  `open()` allows you to pass either 2 *or* 3.

Comment: @Alok: The prototype for `open` is `int open(const char *file, int flags, ...)`.

Comment: @Oli: Oops - I never realized that POSIX prototype for `open` uses varargs.  I always thought `open` had two prototypes.  In my defense, Linux manpage for `open(2)` shows the two different prototypes.  I stand corrected!

Comment: @Alok: I agree, the man pages aren't very helpful in that regard.  But in *their* defence, it's not often that one cares whether POSIX calls are vararg or not!